# Jquery addClass on radio box checked

Tags: jquery, function, click, parent, addclass

I checked all the topics, but i simply don't know why my script does not work :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name=pic]').click(function() {           
    $(this).closest('ul').find(".green").removeClass("green");

    if($(this).is(':checked'))  {
        $(this).closest('ul').find("li").addClass('green');
    }
});
</script>

another script what is making the li tags

var link = document.createElement('li');
var parts = result.tbUrl.split('::');
link.innerHTML = "<label for='asd"+i+"'><img src='"+result.tbUrl+"' /></label><br /><input id='asd"+i+"' type='radio' name='pic'  value='http://"+parts[1]+"' />";
contentDiv.appendChild(link);

etc...

<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="pic" value="asd"/>asd</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="pic" value="b"/>asd</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="pic" value="ba"/>asd</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="pic" value="bs"/>asd</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="pic" value="bc"/>asd</li>
</ul>
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#pic')` is an ID selector, and your inputs don't have IDs. You probably meant `'$('input[name=pic]')`.

Also, you're applying the `green` class to the `<li>`, but then trying to find `.green` elements *inside* the `.parents('li')`. Maybe you want `$(this).closest('ul')` instead?

Comment: Works for me, assuming the script is being executed *after* the `ul` is present in the page (ie. script below ul, or run on document ready). You may also have meant to set the green class on just `$(this).closest('li')` rather than all `li`​s (I'm not sure what exactly you're after here).

Comment: I make the LIs with an another script which create the li elements to the ul#content (called contentDiv).

Comment: Then you will need to bind `click()` *after* those `li`​s have been added, or if you can't do that than use a `live('click')` binding.

Answer (score 0):

bobince is correct. You need to bind in a $(document).ready

I have made the script more efficient too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(':radio[name=pic]').click(function() {           
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("green").end()
           .addClass("green"); //a click always makes a radio button true, so no need to check
        });
    });
</script>
```